# What is the best way to capture still time-lapse from logitech C920 on raspberry pi

Tags: camera, webcam, streaming-video

I'm looking to use a Logitech C920 to capture still images (which I will later sew into a time lapse) Is it possible to use raspi-still to do this? I've read about the streaming solutions and using GSStreamer to stream video, but I'm just looking for a still solution.

Comment: I am going to do something now to capture video using gstremer-omx (Pi Camera module though - but syntax is similar) and output jpg. I hope that I can get a high frame rate so I can use mjpg. with ffmpg it does not work well. Although you can use nginx-rtmp that creates a timelapse video fro you in mp4 based on parameters but you need to compile it. It works well though but you also need to compile ffmpeg(6 hours)... so theres allot of compile time.

Comment: For a quick solution take a look at this. http://www.teslasassistant.com/?p=97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup a cron job to take care of everything for you with what's already installed (after you enable the camera of course):

Open your current cron file:

```
crontab -e
```

Set the job to run every 5 minutes:

```
**/5 ** ** ** ** raspistill -o /home/pi/img-`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"`.png
```

The above will run every 5 minutes, naming the image img-{date format}.png. If you are looking for more information on cron jobs you can see [this article](http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/) and if you're looking for more information about the camera, you can see [this link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/camera)

Edit:
Not 100% sure that the raspistill will work with the usb camera, but you can always write a python script using [pygame's camera](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html). I found some tutorials and docs online and crafted a simple class for taking pictures with python. [You can see it on github here](https://github.com/kyleouellette/pycam). You might have to change the camera device, that's on this line:

```
pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(1024 ,768))
```

So once you pull that repo, you can use a crontab like this:

```
crontab -e
```

and set the command to be:

```
*/5 ** ** ** ** cd path/to/script; python usbcam.py
```

and that should take the picture every 5 minutes, keeping the images in the same directory as the python script. Probably not ideal for file location, but you can change that in the pyimage.image.save method call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the motion package and just use a long interval between automated webcam captures:
http://packages.debian.org/stable/video/motion

Here is also a raspberry pi example:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-a-motion-capture-security-system-using-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Motion has its own timelapse option.